# GeoServer: SQL view layers broken since updating to GeoServer 2.23

Tags: geoserver

We have recently updated from GeoServer 2.19 to 2.23. Since updating all of the SQL view layers are now broken - they can still be accessed via the REST API but when opening via the web interface you get the following error:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: An error occurred while getting the model object for Component: [TextArea [Component id = area, page = org.geoserver.web.data.resource.ResourceConfigurationPage, path = publishedinfo:tabs:panel:theList:1:content:attributePanel:attributesEditor:table:listContainer:items:3:itemProperties:4:component:area, type = org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextArea, isVisible = true, isVersioned = false, markup = [markup = jar:file:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.75/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-web-core-2.23-SNAPSHOT.jar!/org/geoserver/web/data/resource/AttributeTypeInfoEditor.html
<textarea wicket:id="area" class="cql"></textarea>, index = 0, current =  '<textarea wicket:id="area" class="cql">' (line 0, column 0)]]]
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1651)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObjectAsString(Component.java:1674)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.getModelValue(FormComponent.java:1333)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.getValue(FormComponent.java:917)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextArea.onComponentTagBody(TextArea.java:67)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:70)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1649)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.FragmentMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(FragmentMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:89)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1649)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:70)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.renderItem(ListView.java:584)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.renderChild(ListView.java:573)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onRender(AbstractRepeater.java:102)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1649)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:70)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.renderChild(AbstractRepeater.java:115)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onRender(AbstractRepeater.java:102)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1649)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:70)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:800)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.renderAssociatedMarkup(AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:77)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:112)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:800)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.renderAssociatedMarkup(AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:77)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:112)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1649)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:70)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:800)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.renderAssociatedMarkup(AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:77)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:112)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1649)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:70)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.renderItem(ListView.java:584)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.renderChild(ListView.java:573)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onRender(AbstractRepeater.java:102)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:800)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.renderAssociatedMarkup(AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:77)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:112)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAssociatedMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:800)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.renderAssociatedMarkup(AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:77)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(PanelMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:112)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1694)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onComponentTagBody(MarkupContainer.java:1649)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onComponentTagBody(Form.java:1710)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:70)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2606)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1658)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1516)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1719)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:879)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.onRender(WebPage.java:141)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2403)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2331)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1018)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:124)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:236)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:137)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.HTTPMethodFilter.doFilter(HTTPMethodFilter.java:36)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:422)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Error calling method: public java.lang.String org.geoserver.catalog.impl.AttributeTypeInfoImpl.getSource() on object: polygon
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver$MethodGetAndSet.getValue(PropertyResolver.java:940)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver$ObjectWithGetAndSet.getValue(PropertyResolver.java:439)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getValue(PropertyResolver.java:116)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.AbstractPropertyModel.getObject(AbstractPropertyModel.java:86)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1646)
    ... 262 more
Caused by: java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.base/java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.commons.BuildResultStack.peek(BuildResultStack.java:59)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.PolygonBuilder.build(PolygonBuilder.java:51)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQLFilterBuilder.buildPolygon(ECQLFilterBuilder.java:221)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQLCompiler.build(ECQLCompiler.java:411)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQLCompiler.jjtreeCloseNodeScope(ECQLCompiler.java:171)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.generated.parsers.ECQLParser.PolygonText(ECQLParser.java:3507)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.generated.parsers.ECQLParser.PolygonTaggedText(ECQLParser.java:3433)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.generated.parsers.ECQLParser.SimpleGeometryLiteral(ECQLParser.java:1412)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.generated.parsers.ECQLParser.GeometryLiteral(ECQLParser.java:1320)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.generated.parsers.ECQLParser.Expression(ECQLParser.java:2482)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.generated.parsers.ECQLParser.ECQLExpression(ECQLParser.java:116)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.generated.parsers.ECQLParser.ExpressionCompilationUnit(ECQLParser.java:109)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQLCompiler.compileExpression(ECQLCompiler.java:94)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.commons.CompilerUtil.parseExpression(CompilerUtil.java:172)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQL.toExpression(ECQL.java:144)
    at org.geotools.filter.text.ecql.ECQL.toExpression(ECQL.java:125)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.AttributeTypeInfoImpl.getSource(AttributeTypeInfoImpl.java:142)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver$MethodGetAndSet.getValue(PropertyResolver.java:936)
    ... 266 more
```

There haven't been any changes to the underlying database so I'm not sure what has gone wrong. Any ideas? I can't seem to access the final 266 lines of the error. When trying the layer preview I get an 'UndeclaredThrowableException'. Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have attribute customization enabled, without realizing it. The XML for that feature type contains a list of AttributeInfo, while it should really be empty. Go and remove them.

The section that you need to remove looks like this:

```
<attributes>
    <attribute>
      <name>the_geom</name>
      <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
      <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
      <nillable>false</nillable>
    </attribute>
   ...
</attributes>
```

Comment: I have tried the following steps: GET one of the broken layers via the RESTapi, remove attributes section, PUT the layer back. However this returns a 500 error and I can see in the log this is due to a java.util.EmptyStackException. I'm not really sure where to go from here, any suggestions?

Comment: Removing the attributes section works for creating totally new layers. I wasn't able to get it working for the layers broken in the update but it works if this is done via the backend rather than the api